# ms sql grouping results query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I basically have a transaction table I have created that records invoices in and out. 
I have a flag for sales (=1) and purchases (=2).

I want a simple sql that calculates the sales and purchases by month. 
Problem is, if I remove the transaction type (mybooks_trans_class_id_fk) from the group by it doesnt work, but if I leave it in the results are not what I want.

**SQL:**

```
       SELECT 
        DATEPART(Year, mybooks_trans_transaction_datetime) as 'sales_year',
        DATEPART(Month, mybooks_trans_transaction_datetime) as 'sales_month',
        case 
        when cast( mybooks_trans_class_id_fk as nvarchar(100))!='1' then cast(sum(mybooks_trans_gross_amount) as nvarchar(100))
        else '0' 
        end as total_sales,

        case 
        when cast( mybooks_trans_class_id_fk as nvarchar(100))!='2' then cast(sum(mybooks_trans_gross_amount) as nvarchar(100))  
        else '0' 
        end as total_purchases         
        from view_mybooks_transactions_all_details 
        GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, mybooks_trans_transaction_datetime), 
        DATEPART(MM, mybooks_trans_transaction_datetime),mybooks_trans_class_id_fk
```

**Results are:**

```
2012     11 0   15300.00

2012     12 0   2500.00

2013    1   0   1300.00

2013    1   600.00  0

2013    2   0   2750.00

2013    2   1500.00 0
```

But I want the month 1 for example to be in one row only so the results I want are

```
2012    11  0   15300.00

2012    12  0   2500.00

2013    1   600.00  1300.00

2013    2   1500.00 2750.00
```

Any suggestions? My sql ability is moderate at best!

Answer (score 2):

This should work: (tried not to change too much)

```
SELECT 
  DATEPART(Year, mybooks_trans_transaction_datetime) as 'sales_year',
  DATEPART(Month, mybooks_trans_transaction_datetime) as 'sales_month',
  SUM(case 
      when mybooks_trans_class_id_fk != 1
      then mybooks_trans_gross_amount
      else 0
      end) as total_sales,
  SUM(case 
      when mybooks_trans_class_id_fk != 2
      then mybooks_trans_gross_amount
      else 0
      end) as total_purchases
FROM view_mybooks_transactions_all_details 
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, mybooks_trans_transaction_datetime), 
         DATEPART(MM, mybooks_trans_transaction_datetime)
```